# Jmeter Executions running in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, jmeter, bearer-token

I have 2 thread groups , one generates a bearer token and the other makes use of it. I want thread group2 to make use of bearer token from 1 . But i  want thread group 1 to execute only once every 4 minutes but at the same time Thread group 2 should run parallelly and indefinitely by making using of the bearer token from thread group 1

I added the basic setup , i.e thread group to create a bearer token and thread group 2 that runs indefinitely by making using of the bearer token . But i'm not able to

1. schedule or loop the first thread group to run only once every 4 minutes
   2 . to make second thread group run parallelly

Answer (score 0):

1. `schedule or loop the first thread group to run only once every 4 minutes` - add [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or [Flow Control Action Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) and introduce a pause of 240000 milliseconds
2. `to make second thread group run parallelly` - untick the corresponding box on the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level

   [image]

More information: [Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables)

Answer (score 0):

**Thread Group-1:** schedule or loop the first thread group to run only once every 4 minutes.

- Capture the Bearer token in a parameter and save it in a CSV file
- Based on your requirement each time it runs you can make it overwrite or keep adding new lines to the existing CSV data file
- Set a 4 min Constant Timer for this thread group

**Thread Group-2:** run parallel

- Run this thread group parallelly feeding test data (Bearer token) from the CSV file created by the Thread Group-1

The JMX would look something like this-
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOTfO.png)

**Test PLan Settings:** at the test plan level settings check the box "Run Thread Groups Consecutively-
[Screenahot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me0OP.png)